# How to query to get all documents referenced to another collection based on one field as username

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my Node API and MongoDB, I'm trying to make an endpoint to get all the posts associated with one username of a profile. In my Profile schema, I have a reference to the Post Schema and in my Post schema, I have a reference to the Username from Profile schema. 
My issue I don't know how to get all the posts for that username. I did similarly but with embedded for the Experience schema but I'm not sure how to do that for the referenced collections.

Post model:

```
const { Connect } = require("../db");

const reactionSchema = {
    likedBy: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    }
};

const postSchema = {
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        sparse: false
    },    
    username: {
        type: Connect.Schema.Types.String,
        ref: "Profile"
    },    
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
        required: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },    
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },    
    reactions: [reactionSchema],    
    comments: {
        type: Connect.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
        required: false
    }
};

const collectionName = "post";
const postSchemaModel = Connect.Schema(postSchema);
const Post = Connect.model(collectionName, postSchemaModel);

module.exports = Post;
```

Profile model:

```
// Here defining profile model
// Embedded we have the Experience as []
const { Connect } = require("../db");
const { isEmail } = require("validator");

const postSchema = {
    type: Connect.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post"
};

const experienceSchema = {
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },    
    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },    
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },    
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    }
};

const profileSchema = {
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },   
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },    
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "Email is required"],
        validate: {
            validator: string => isEmail(string),
            message: "Provided email is invalid"
        }
    },    
    bio: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },    
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },    
    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },    
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    },    
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },    
    experience: [experienceSchema],
    posts: [postSchema],    
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },    
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    }
};

const collectionName = "profile";
const profileSchemaModel = Connect.Schema(profileSchema);
const Profile = Connect.model(collectionName, profileSchemaModel);

module.exports = Profile;
```

I was able to make this for the embedded experience but not sure that correct for referenced collection:

```
const profileWithExperiences = await Student.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: res.username.username } },
  {
    $unwind: "$experience"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "experience._id": new ObjectID(req.params.experienceId)
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      username: 1,
      experience: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
]);
```

I would like to see an example for referenced collections as it is confusing me how should I do that

[EDIT]
JSON for Profiles and Posts

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e2c98fc3d785252ce5b5693"),
    "imageUrl": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
    "firstname": "Jakos",
    "surname": "Lemi",
    "email": "lemi@email.com",
    "bio": "My bio bio",
    "title": "Senior IT developer",
    "area": "Copenhagen",
    "username": "Jakos",
    "experience": [
        {
            "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
            "_id": ObjectId("5e3975f95fbeec9095ff3d2f"),
            "role": "Developer",
            "company": "Google",
            "startDate": ISODate("2018-11-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate": ISODate("2019-01-05T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "area": "Copenhagen",
            "createdAt": ISODate("2020-02-04T13:47:37.167Z"),
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-04T13:47:37.167Z")
        },
        {
            "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
            "_id": ObjectId("5e3978bf5e399698e20c56d4"),
            "role": "Developer",
            "company": "IBM",
            "startDate": ISODate("2018-11-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate": ISODate("2019-01-05T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "area": "Copenhagen",
            "createdAt": ISODate("2020-02-04T13:59:27.412Z"),
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-04T13:59:27.412Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-01-25T19:37:32.727Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-04T23:14:37.122Z"),
    "__v": NumberInt("0")
}
```

Post

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5e3beb639e072afedd19dcef"),
    "username": ObjectId("5e2c98fc3d785252ce5b5693"),
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    "text": "My awesome post",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-02-06T10:33:07.22Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-06T10:33:07.22Z"),
    "reactions": [ ],
    "__v": NumberInt("0")
}
```

Output expected:

```
{
    "username": "Jakos",
    "postsCount": [1],
    "posts": [
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e3beb639e072afedd19dcef"),
        "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
        "text": "My awesome post",
        "createdAt": ISODate("2020-02-06T10:33:07.22Z"),
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-02-06T10:33:07.22Z"),
        "reactions": [ ],
        "__v": NumberInt("0")
    }
    ]

}
```

I want to see all the posts related to that username

Comment: Jakub can you add sample documents (in json format)  for the related collections? Also it would be good if you could describe the expected result.

Comment: Please check I added what you asked for

Comment: Jakub why do you need `$match: {
      "experience._id": new ObjectID(req.params.experienceId)
    }`?

Comment: Also I guess we need userId in the posts collection to make a connection between profiles and posts.

Comment: That was just an example I get one experience for a profile in an embedded situation as I need it by ID and the ID is ObjectID. I found that solution with the experiences embedded inside the profile collection.

Comment: I have to use this `username: {
        type: Connect.Schema.Types.String,
        ref: "Profile"
    },` as a connection to the Profile I was asked to make from here by username

Comment: Ok, your sample post document didn't contain it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207353/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-jakub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation to join collections.

```js
db.profiles.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      username: "Jakos"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",   //the name of the posts collection, change this if it is different
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "username",
      as: "posts"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      username: 1,
      posts: 1,
      postsCount: {
        $size: "$posts"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lrS0P700KFA)

For `mongoose` it should be like this in your app:

```js
const profileWithExperiences = await Student.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: res.username.username } },
  {
    $unwind: "$experience"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts", //the name of the posts collection, change this if it is different
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "username",
      as: "posts"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      username: 1,
      posts: 1,
      postsCount: {
        $size: "$posts"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get like this i am getting data from two table with the use of node and mongodb.

```
var param = {};
    param['user_id']=id;
    var search={ user_id:param.user_id,status: [ 'Pending', 'Accepted' ] };
    var output={};
    output = await JobRequest.find(search); 
    if(output !=0)
    {
            var JSon=await JobRequest.aggregate([
                {$match: { user_id: {$gte:id}}  }, 
                     {
                     "$project": {
                      "employee_id": {
                        "$toObjectId": "$employee_id"
                      }, 
                      "service_id": {
                        "$toObjectId": "$service_id"
                      }, 
                      "createdDate": {
                        "$toString": "$createdDate"
                      }, 
                      "chat_status": {
                        "$toString": "$chat_status"
                      },    
                      "status": {
                        "$toString": "$status"
                      },                      
                      "delivery_address": {
                        "$toString": "$delivery_address"
                      },                 
                      "delivery_lat": {
                        "$toString": "$delivery_lat"
                      },         
                      "delivery_lang": {
                        "$toString": "$delivery_lang"
                      },
                    }
                     },

                     {
                      $lookup:
                         {
                            from: "employees",
                            localField: "employee_id",
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "employee_details"
                        }
                   },
                   {
                      $lookup:
                         {
                            from: "services",
                            localField: "service_id",
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "service_details"
                        }
                   }
               ]);
```

Comment: Honestly, I do not get this as this is related to a search query and in my situation,
I need to get all the posts related to the username. I would like to see an example with my data I shared please