# Mongodb / mongoose - Referencing or embedding id's of other documents look the same - what is the difference?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, embedding

I have a product model. I reference other products under 'similarProducts'. I dont understand the difference of me having a reference or just embedding data.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String
    },
    hasReport: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    reports: [ReportSchema],
    similarProducts: {
     name: {
            type: [String]
        },
        id: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }]
    }
}
mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

I have added the similar products manually to my db. I have added manually the names and id's of 'other products', now what I see inside my db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("gdfbhert"),
    "name" : "product 1",
    "similarProducts" : {
        "name" : [
            "product 5",
            "product 9"
        ],
        "id" : [
            "abcde",
            "a1b2c3d4"
        ]
    },
    "reports" : []
}
```

I might just not understand how it all works and it might be a stupid question but I just want to understand the impact of having references! In my examle, couldnt I just have embedded the names and id's without stating a reference?!

```
...
    similarProducts: {
     name: {
            type: [String]
        },
        id: [String]
    }
...
```

Could someone explain to me the difference? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes it is possible to embed just the names, but then how you can get the related products list in the product detail page? And also if the product names change, the embedded names will be incorrect. You just need to embed the product Ids.

Comment: thank you for your reply. so if I have a reference to the other products and I that other products name changes, it will change automatically without me doing anything in my db?! Also in my code, when I am fetching similar products, I fetch them using findById, so I display the name and onclick I fetch by id. If I just embed the id, without referencing the other product, wouldnt I also be able to fetch them?! So I still dont understand the difference.

Comment: You can get the related embedded products in one db call using mongoose populate or mongodb lookup aggregation.

Comment: you can check this answer for popupate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454400/11717458  and this answer for lookup https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096006/11717458

Comment: ah okay so I actually dont need the names then, because I can only reference other products using id's and then populate the names?! Can you pls also answer my question as to what happens if a products name changes -if (by using a reference) that change will be reflected on automatically in my db? Or did you mean - because I can populate the names, thats how I would always get the right product even if the name changes since I populate?!

Comment: If you reference the related products, and the related product names change, it won't be a problem (will be reflected automatically) when you popupate